# How to change label in customer dashboard magento2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I have created custom module in **Magento2**. I have created succesfuly added custom link in customer dashboard. But I want to change existing label of customer dashboard account. I have attached screenshot.

[image]

Please Give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. You can change the label using xml

Just go to below location

> magento_root\app\design\frontend\ {Package}\ {theme}\Magento_Customer\layout

create an `.xml` file there with name **`customer_account.xml`**

Put the below code there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
      <body>
            <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Orders</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
     </body>
</page>
```

To get the actual file with this settings you can have as a reference file available at the below location

> `magento_root\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\customer_account.xml`

2. The other way is via `en_US.csv` file.

For this just create an en_US. csv file at the below location

> magento_root\app\code\Package\Module\i18n

Put there below code in `en_US.csv` file

```
"My Orders","Orders"
```

Revert back if facing any problem.

Comment: If my answer helped you just vote it so that it can help others as well facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You can change your label if you create translation file in CSV format. In your module create a directory "i18n" and and your transalation.